# How to implement a basic pointer

Tags: java, pointers

I know here is no pointer in Java. But how do I change a value in the calling scope? For instance, I want to write a function that takes an integer num, set the integer to 0 if it's greater than 21, otherwise do nothing.
In the main, my code is as follow:

```
int a=34;
KillOver21(a);
System.out.print(a);
```

I expect an 0.

Comment: Why not just return your value from the function?

Comment: You can only do this with mutable types.

Comment: The fact that Java doesn't have pointers is irrelevant. In the Pascal sense, it *does* have pointers. What matters is that it doesn't have pass-by-reference.

Comment: Chances are, if you need to do this, it's not idomiatic/java-like.  every language lends itself to its own way of thinking and approaching problems and you can usually approach whatever problem you have in real life from a way that doesn't involve pass by reference.

Answer (score 4):

Java is [pass by value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm), so a copy of the parameter a is sent to the method, so modification to `a` in the method will not affect the original argument `a` in `main`

The max you can do is `return int` from `KillOver21(a)` method

```
int z = KillOver21(a); // This will return 0
System.out.print(z);
```

But you can achieve something like that with custom objects, say you have a class

```
class AHolder {

    public int a;

}
```

then you can expect `AHolder` instance to change

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
     AHolder a = new AHolder();
     a.a = 34;
     killOver21(a);
     System.out.println(a.a);
}

public static void killOver21(AHolder b) {
    if(b.a > 21) {
       b.a = 0;
    }
}
```

Since in the latter (even if its *Pass by Value*) , the **reference is copied** and both **reference point to same object**. So changes made inside the `killOver21` method actually **changes the object**.

[image]

Comment: Or, you could use an object, which would be pass by reference.

Comment: @Timothy Jones: No, be careful, even if you use a type that inherits from `Object` it is *still* passed by value.

Comment: Well, technically speaking, the `Object` is passed by the value of its reference handle. So, if you use a mutable type, and pass it in, you could change it using a setter, resulting in the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Timothy Jones: So, [I'm technically correct---the best kind of correct](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo).

Answer (score 3):

It is simply not possible, Java supports **pass by value**. `int a`'s value will be copied to the function.

You could use `Object` instead of primitive where the reference value will be copied to your function by which you can get the actual object and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally impossible in Java, period. `int` are immutable, and passed by value. You would *need* to create a mutable `int` type:

```
class MutableInt {
    private int value;

    public MutableInt(int value) { this.value = value; }

    public getValue() { return this.value; }
    public setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Then:

```
void KillOver21(MutableInt m) {
    if(m.getValue() > 21) { m.setValue(0); }
}
```

However, be aware the mutable types that represent concepts that are defined by their value rather than their identity are generally *an extremely bad idea*. But, this is the only way to achieve what you're trying to achieve. Again, I caution you with the strongest words: what you're doing is a *bad* idea. You should find another way.

Doc, it hurts when I do this.

Then don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way (quick&dirty) is to put value within an array

```
int holder[] = new int[]{ a};

KillOver21(holder)

System.out.printf( "value=[%d]", holder[0]  );

void KillOver21(int holder[] ) {
    holder[0] = 0;
 }
```